# `Decodable` customization

Tags: serialization, rust

I want to deserialize a configuration structure like this:

```rust
#[deriving(Clone, PartialEq, Decodable, Show)]
pub struct Config {
    network1: Network,
    network2: Network
}

#[deriving(Clone, PartialEq, Decodable, Show)]
pub struct Network {
    interface: Option<String>,
    prefer: Option<AddressPreference>,
    address: Option<String>,
    port: u16
}

#[deriving(Clone, PartialEq, Show)]
pub enum AddressPreference {
    IPv4, IPv6, Any
}
```

It forms a tree of `struct`s and enums. But the decoder I want to use does not support enums, so I thought that I will be able to represent the enum as a string by implementing `Decodable` for the enum which matches on strings. But I don't know how to do it properly.

The main problem is that I don't know how to write `Decodable` implementation which handles errors correctly. If I write

```rust
impl<E, D: Decoder<E>> Decodable<D, E> for AddressPreference { ... }
```

the only way I can indicate parsing error is `fail!()` - I don't know actual error type, so I can't create its instance. This is unacceptable.

Buf if I write

```rust
impl Decodable<toml::Decoder, toml::Error> for AddressPreference { ... }
```

that is, binding `Decodable` instance to concrete decoder type (which is fine for me), I lose automatic deriving of outer structures, because they are implemented for generic decoder and error:

```
src/sfc/config.rs:11:30: 11:39 error: expected serialize::serialize::Decodable<__D,__E>, but found serialize::serialize::Decodable<rust-toml::Decoder,rust-toml::Error> (expected type parameter but found struct rust-toml::Decoder)
src/sfc/config.rs:11 #[deriving(Clone, PartialEq, Decodable, Show)]
```

What should I do in this case? I guess, the proper answer in this particular case is submitting a pull request to the library enabling support for enums serialization, but I think that the question is more broad. What it the library supported enums, but I wanted to customize decoding nonetheless?

Comment: I think you wrote a few `Decodable`s where you meant `Decoder`? But yes, it appears the only way to construct a generic error is using return values of the `Decoder` methods directly. I opened an issue: [#15036](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/15036).

Comment: @dbaupp, I'm not sure whether you're referring to the question itself or to the code I wrote, but I've just reread the question and can say that everything in it is formulated correctly. Thanks for filing the issue, BTW.

Comment: I believe the code in the question is not correct: AFAICT `impl<E, D: Decodable<E>> Decodable<D, E> ...` should be `D: Decoder<E>`.

Comment: @dbaupp, yes, you're right, my fault. Fixed.